# Validate so that no special characters are allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

How can I validate `:title` in my model so that only the letters a-z, A-z, and 0-9 are accepted?

```
  validates :title, :format => { with: REGULAR EXPRESSION , :message => 'no special characters, only letters and numbers' }
```

What should the regular expression be?

Comment: Oh I see I missed that :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The regular expression would be `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`

You basically define three ranges of symbols that are allowed, first a-z, then A-Z and finally 0-9.

The asterisk in the end then defines that zero or more of the previously stated characters need to be matched, that means that an empty title would be allowed. If you want at least one character, use a `+` instead of the `*`. Or if you want more than three characters, use `{3,}` instead of the asterisk.

Comment: Wouldn't this validate an empty title?

Comment: Yes it would. You could replace the asterisk by a + to enforce at least one character.

Comment: Your regex could be simplified to `/\w/`: http://rubular.com/r/7kA4JHjwD4 --- I would allow the spaces too (your regexp does not catch it): `/(\w|\s)/`

Comment: `/\w/` allows underscores.

Comment: With this expression the validation passes if the title contains at least one character in the 3 ranges. How do I make it so that only these characters are accepted

Comment: No, it validates if it has at least one character in *any* of the three ranges.

Comment: `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\s)/`

Comment: Or may be `/[^\W_]+/`

Comment: thanks @Lukas_Skywalker , you also have to add :multiline => true if you want to use the $ anchor

Comment: You should use `/\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/`. If you use only `^...$` it will validate only first line of string, e.g. `"asdffs\n$&" =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/` will return `0` and condition will pass. With `\A...\z` it looks `"asdffs\n&" =~ /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/` and returns `nil`. Therefore don't use `^...$` unless you want to test only first line of string.

Comment: I've tried all of these solutions for a single line name field. They all either block valid names with no special characters or allow special characters. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JesseNovotny try the one in the answer but remove the leading `^` and the trailing `$`

Comment: This one is returning an error: "The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option? (ArgumentError)"